Does Acts 13:15 imply the synagogues were very social and allowed strangers to speak to the congregation?
I never noticed before but I have wondered how the Apostles were always freely given the opportunity to preach in the synagogues? In our modern day churches (aside from some charismatics) allowing someone not well known to speak to the congregation is almost unheard of.
The verse that came to my attention is Acts 13:15
Acts 13:15 ESV

[15] After the reading from the Law and the Prophets, the rulers of
the synagogue sent a message to them, saying, “Brothers, if you have
any word of encouragement for the people, say it.”

Does this mean strangers who visited other churches (who appeared normal I guess?) were commonly given a warm hand of fellowship and offered to share?
Are there any other scriptures indicating an affirmative or negative to this idea?
Not sure if this relates to the free ability to publicly raise questions? For example, Jesus at the temple as a child.  I can’t imagine how a child (not allowed to speak of course) could yet be able to debate or ask questions with the pastor of a modern church? Not sure what it is but something seems different.

I'm not sure this can be categorically answered from scripture. I have always assumed that in conversation prior to the meeting, the apostles' speech was so prudent, wise, knowledgeable , dignified and edifying that the elders present deemed it proper to invite them to address the congregation. There are some communities who would do likewise today but probably not within structured denominationalism subject to a 'headquarters'. Up-voted +1.

I think there are 2 possibilities, one they were complete strangers and allowed to talk, or the rulers had heard of the apostles and wanted to here a message in person when they visited.

@NigelJ Agreed.  This might be a better question for History.SE, or possibly Judaism.SE.

Synagogue Visitors The N.T. Scriptures relate many, many times about Jesus going to synagogues and speaking about the Kingdom. So Paul did nothing unusual when he addressed the local congregations, as well. That this is a hermeneutically correct deduction was underscored when my uncle (a Christian minister) was asked to address the local congregation when he visited a Congregation in California! Congeniality with "strangers" is a benefit to social acceptance in any culture.

In most modern Christian churches, the services are conducted by someone that is a figure of authority, presenting the official views of God, the Church, and its hierarchy to the congregation.
This is generally based on a simplification of the Israelite priesthood in the Jerusalem Temple.
It would have been very inappropriate for anyone other than a Priest or Sadducee to speak to the people.
The Synagogues were places where intelligent but ordinary men (Rabbis) taught the common people the details of their history and how to live one's life (as defined by the Pharisees).
They spoke with a voice of knowledge, not of divine authority.
Of course one could pray at a Synagogue, and there were formal ceremonies, but it wouldn't be at the same level as the Jerusalem Temple.
Mostly the Synagogue was a place to discuss and learn.
It would not have been unusual for anyone, even a stranger, to present a short speech and to start a discussion on some specific topic.

Daily life in the time of Jesus
by Daniel-Rops, Henri, 1901-1965
Publication date 1962
Pages 414–420
The Synagogue: In No Way a Temple
The religious organization that had taken on so great an importance was that meeting, that assembly (assembly is the meaning of the word name by which it was ordinarily called), which we have already seen playing a considerable part in the administrative and judicial life of the Jews, and even in their education: the beth ha-keneseth, the synagogue.
But those were only its secondary functions: the synagogue certainly governed the daily life of its members, appointed the local magistrates, saw to the teaching of the children and even constituted in itself a little university for the people; but it did so because it was primarily a beth ha-tefillah, a house of prayer, where men met to hear God speak by means of the words of His Law.
What was the origin of the synagogue? The most usual view is that it began in Babylon during the exile, as a substitute for the worship at the Temple, and that Ezra brought it into Palestine after the return.
Others think that it was invented by Ezra and Nehemiah to strengthen their government.
According to some rabbis and to some recent scholars, however, the synagogue is far older, going back before the destruction of the Temple by Nebuchadnezzar to the reforms of Josiah or even to those “missions of Levites and priests’ who went out in the time of king Jehosaphat to teach the Law in all the cities of Judah, as we read in the Bible (2 Par. 17:7-9).
At all events, there are papyri that prove the existence of synagogues in Egypt in the third century B.c., and Josephus speaks of one in Antioch under the descendants of Antiochus Epiphanes.
It is therefore exceedingly probable that by the time Our Lord went into the synagogue of Capharnaum to take part in the traditional prayers and readings, Palestine and the whole of the Diaspora had for centuries been accustomed to that institution which has given Judaism its particular physiognomy right up to the present day.
Each village had its own synagogue, and each town had several.
Any Jew who chose might erect one or, if he preferred, turn his own house into a synagogue.
The associations of men of the same trade or professions had theirs, just as in the Middle Ages the guilds had their particular churches and chapels.
The Jews of the Diaspora built special synagogues for themselves in Jerusalem, and it was in these that they met when they came on pilgrimage.
The Acts mention some of these, as the synagogue of the Freedmen, of the Cyreneans and Alexandrians, and of those who came from Cilicia and Asia—very reminiscent of the foreigners’ churches in Rome: the French church of Saint Louis, for example, or the Spaniards’ Saint James’.
It was said that there were between four and five hundred synagogues in Jerusalem, some of them standing in rows: in the same way the mosques, in the Mohammedan world, often bear no proportion to the number of a town’s inhabitants.
“Synagogue” stood for both congregation and its place of meeting: in just the same way the church, the ecclesia or assembly, sat in a religious building which took on the same name.
As far as it was possible, the synagogue was situated high up in the town or village, for, as the rabbis said, “no man should live higher than the synagogue.” At the same time they did their best to set it by a source of fresh water, to make the ritual ablutions easier.
In the Acts we see Saint Paul at Philippi in Macedonia “going out beyond the city gates, by the river side, a meeting-place, we were told, for prayer.”
The architecture of the synagogue was plain and adapted to the local style.
The building, in essence, consisted of a rectangular hall, with columns dividing it into three aisles and supporting a gallery that ran round it, no doubt reserved for the women.
There were three doors into the building, and in front of them a flight of steps.
The more important synagogues, such as that of Capharnaum, for example, which has been excavated, but which is some two hundred years later than that in which Our Lord would have seen, had a covered portico running along one side, with water for the ablutions flowing into a basin in the middle of it.
Leaning against the outside wall of the synagogue there would be the little rooms that were used for the school or for lodging pilgrims.
The decoration of the synagogues was also of the simplest kind: there might be palms painted on the plaster or the stucco, the fiveor six-pointed star, and the seven-branched candlestick: at the time of Christ, the Mosaic prohibition against the representation of animals or men was still observed, though later it fell into disuse.
As the synagogue was in no way a place of worship, in the strict sense of the priestly celebration of a cult, it (like a mosque) had no altar.
In something like a very small chapel, shut off by a curtain, there was the holy chest or cupboard, the tebah, which also had the ancient biblical name of aron, the ark.
Here were kept the precious scrolls, the Law and the Sepharim, preserved in a leather case and wrapped in linen.
Beside them stood the horns and trumpets that were used for proclaiming fasts and holidays; and before the ark there were lamps continually burning.
There was a platform or a pulpit for the reader who, turned towards Jerusalem, would comment upon the holy text.
The congregation had benches or stools, and there was a great deal of competition for those in the front row: “Their heart is set on taking the chief places at table and the first seats in the synagogue,” said Christ, in scorn of the Pharisees.
People would come early to take them, and some would go so far as to oil the hazzan’s palm to have them reserved.
Before the service it was usual to sprinkle the floor with an infusion of mint, to purify the air.
The meetings and the subsidiary activities of the synagogue were managed by a small committee.
It was entirely democratic: a council of ten elders, traditionally called “the founders,’ elected one “ruler of the synagogue,” or sometimes three.
In any case, there was one president, one real leader, like Jairus at Capharnaum.
This was the system that the primitive Church adopted.
The leader and the council decided upon the admission of proselytes, looked to the financial administration of the community, appointed the local judges and schoolmasters and arbitrated in the case of dispute between members of the congregation.
The hazzan was their factotum: servant, sexton, beadle, caretaker, the person who carried out their sentences, and even, if there were no appointed schoolmaster, teacher.
He was an indispensable man, and he was aware of it: he was a person of real standing in the community.
The wealthy synagogues also had employees of a lower grade: teachers, almscollectors, trumpeters.
But generally speaking those tasks were undertaken by members of the congregation; and it was the congregation, also, that provided those who officiated at the services.
The Services at the Synagogue
The services, too, were marked by their simplicity.
The synagogue opened three times a day for those who wished to come and pray; and the Shema and the Shemoneh Esreh were recited, On the second and the fifth days of the week (that is, our Monday and Thursday), which were market-days and days upon which the judges sat, there was a more important meeting, one at which the assembled men from the countryside were reminded of the truths of the Law.
But it was the Sabbath that was the chief day, and all the members of the community who were healthy then came to the main service of the week.
Three men, or even one alone, were enough on the other days, but the Sabbath service required seven to officiate; and these seven were called in turn by the hazzan.
In all cases the presence of ten men of Israel in the congregation was required before a meeting was complete under the Law.
There was nothing, nothing whatever, in this service that was in any way reminiscent of the service of the Temple: it had nothing sacrificial about it.
Custom had fixed the order of its performance, and thus was quite invariable.
It began with prayers: the congregation, standing and facing towards Jerusalem, recited the Shema and the Shemoneh Esreh; or rather one man, standing before the ark, recited them aloud while the congregation prayed silently and then in a loud voice responded with the Amen that marked their souls’ participation
in the sacred words and their agreement with them.
Any one of the faithful might fulfil this important office once he had come of age according to the Law, once he had become a man from the point of view of religion at the age of thirteen; and it may well have been that Our Lord prayed thus among His own people.
After the prayers came the essence of the service, the reading of the Law.
The hazzan took the holy scroll first from the ark and then from its two wrappings, and offered it to the first of the seven readers.
True reading was required, and it was forbidden to utter more than one verse by heart.
The text was divided into just 153 parts, so that the whole of the Pentateuch was read through in a little less than three years.
(It was only later, and in Babylon, that these divisions were made three times as long, in order that the entirety of the Law should be read in one year.) The hazzan stood by the reader, and if in reading he made a mistake, the hazzan corrected it: if the hazzan saw that a passage was coming that might shock the people or make them laugh, he stopped the reader.
Each verse, as it was read in Hebrew, was translated into Aramaic, so that everybody should understand.
All lectors were allowed to make a commentary upon the text they had just read; and for this they usually sat down.
The comments might take the form of a homily or of an exposition, a midrash whose length would vary according to the speaker.
There were some commentators of great reputation, just as there are well-known preachers today, and they were much in request in the synagogues: Jesus, and later Saint Paul, would certainly have been among these.
Added to this central body of the services there were various elements that might differ from synagogue to synagogue: these were further readings and prayers, analogous to the last Gospel and the prayers below the altar that in the course of time have been added to the mass.
One of the readers then read the “last lesson,” which was always taken from the prophets.
The man who did this was said to be maphtir, or to perform maphtir: it was thus that Our Lord, one day in the synagogue of Nazareth, performed maphtir.
The reader quoted three verses at the most, which he had chosen beforehand and meditated upon— Our Lord took two—and then he spoke upon them.
In the same
way it is very usual, in a Christian pulpit, to begin a sermon by a scriptural text, which is subsequently developed and commented upon.
In the synagogue the commentary upon the prophets was obligatorily made in Aramaic.
Lastly the man who had recited the first prayers returned to the place before the tebah to say the final prayer.
This ended with a blessing, which had to be said without a pause and without drawing breath.
It seems that in some synagogues at this stage the people sang from the Book of Psalms, that famous biblical collection having become the Jewish communities’ book of religious songs, as it was to be that of the Christian Church.
On going out, each person gave alms to the collectors who were in charge of the poor, and since gifts in kind were taken as well as money, the doorway and the porch of the synagogue were littered with a diversity of goods.
The whole service would have lasted about an hour.
The importance of the synagogue and what it stood for in the life of Israel at the time of Christ cannot be over-estimated.
What the town-hall and the church were for the medieval town, the synagogue was for the Jews.
Everybody, without exception, went to the synagogue, not only for the services, but also for all administrative and judicial business.
To be expelled from the synagogue was a disgrace; and thus, as Saint John observes, when the spreading of belief in Christ began to worry the Jews they came “to an agreement that anyone who acknowledged Jesus as the Christ should be forbidden the synagogue.
Throughout the Diaspora, it was the synagogue that ensure the Jewish community’s union, kept faith alive, and prevented the believers from being swallowed up in the mass of heathendom.
It has been said that the synagogue set itself up against the Temple as its rival.
But it does not appear that this was true at the time of Christ.
The synagogue was then rather the Temple’s antechamber, and it replaced the Temple for those who were unable to go up to Jerusalem.
Yet it is quite certain that the spirit of the two institutions was not the same: on the one hand we have a solemn liturgical ritual of sacrifices, a most complex ceremonial; and on the other nothing but plain reading and prayers.
In a way, the Christian mass was to be a blending of the two, the Eucharist being spiritually linked with the idea of sacrifice and the rest of the service being made up of prayers and reading, as in the synagogue.
In reality, once the synagogue had taken its predominant place in Jewish life, Israel no longer needed the Temple.
What is more, the future of Israel’s religion was assured from that moment on; for it could live independently of any sacred building and any particular worship.
It had become a religion based on the Word, a purely doctrinal religion.
Besides, it was in the synagogues themselves, to a large extent, that the innumerable commentators formed the tradition that the Talmud was to enshrine.
The Romans might destroy the Temple, but it was beyond their power to prevent the Jewish communities scattered throughout their empire from meeting on the Sabbath day to pray to God and to read His Law.
The Jews were conquered and dispersed, but Judaism survived because from that time onwards each believer carried within him the true essence of his worship: wherever there were gathered ten believers in the One God, there Israel was in existence, and God was with Israel.
The true religious life had become spiritual.
When the scribe Ezra accustomed his people to meeting regularly for prayer after the return from the Babylonian captivity, did he foresee the prodigious consequences of his act?


+1 for some useful quote  about the Synagogue. Not sure it really nails down how open to allow others to speak (or even question publicly another teacher like the little boy Jesus was able to do in the temple) but still valuable. Interesting there were 400-500 of them in Israel alone. I would co sider the temple a lot different as a lot of it was private and the sheer size of being able to accommodate 100,00 or 200,00

THE SYNAGOGEEthnic Fellowship The answer is found in the cultural and socio-political setting of the first century. The Jewish people were zealous in keeping ethnic purity, so stayed by themselves in the largely Gentile cultures throughout the Roman Empire. (Although they engaged in the public international marketplaces freely.) When ten families united in a locality, a Synagogue "society" was formally formed.
Out of the necessities of survival they were tight-knit culturally, but even if Jewish men from another Roman city arrived, they would not be unwelcome, NOR considered strangers/foreigners of sorts. Notice the use of the word, "brothers", in this verse under consideration! (Acts 13:15)
Sabbath Service Assembling on the Sabbath would be just as a welcoming event as someone entering a modern Church with a door-greeter welcoming all the visitors. Even though an unfamiliar face, the Ruler of the synagogue would be more than willing to get information from a visiting Jew---especially if he had any news from Jerusalem, or the latest teaching from one of the famous rabbinical schools. The rumors about the commotion caused by Jesus would be if interest, and so Paul's info would be welcome---although Paul's deductions about it was to be highly controversial!
Note that the "synagogue" institution was much more than a place of congregational worship. It was a hub of Jewish community affairs: education, administration, politics, charity, judiciary proceedings, news, etc. for the local Jewish community.
Order of Service Jesus was often the speaker in most of the synagogues He visited during His ministry. The N.T. recorded this many, many times. (Matthew 4:23, 9:35, 12:9, 13:54, Mark 1:21, 1:39, 3:1, 6:2, Luke 4:15, 4:44, 6:6, 13:10, John 6:59, 18:20) So the acceptance of Paul by rulers of the synagogue was not unusual, but customary. So the visiting Paul was accustomed to speak everywhere he went. (Acts 9:20, 13:5, 13:14, 14:1, 15:21, 17:1, 10, 17, 18:4, 19, 26, 19:8)
The "order of service" cannot be compared to modern Catholic or Protestant church meetings. The small community of Jews in a synagogue enmeshed in a gentile city  would be more conducive to "sharing the pulpit," than a modern city church (mega-church?) that is a country that is more friendly to Christianity, and that has hundreds of churches dotted throughout its streets.
[As an aside, I am reminded of a Jamaican church in London wherein I spoke, that had an "open pulpit" for anyone who wanted to speak during the service-and there were very many!---As well, the congeniality of local synagogues is underscored by recalling that my uncle (a Christian minister) was invited to speak at a local synagogue when he visited it.
Synagogue Discipline It should be noted that while visitors were invited to speak freely, their message was not often well received! The Rulers of the synagogue did not hesitate to execute their disapproval if they did not consider the message valid. Many times their response was "violent."
Jesus warned His disciples about this several times. They will scourge you! They will put you out of the synagogue! (Matthew 10:17, 23:34, Mark 13:9, Luke 21:12; John 5:22, 12:42, 16:2; See also Acts 22:19, 26:11 where Paul aided the Rulers in violently expelling the people of the Way, i.e. Christians)
THE TEMPLEThe example of Jesus talking with the Rabbis and Lawyers in the Temple at age 12 is a wholly different matter. The Temple area was not the meeting place of a synagogue.
Rather the Temple proper was located in a large bit of acreage where there were also many other buildings: priests' homes, tool sheds for the sacrificial implements, tax collectors buildings, storage rooms for the tithes, Sanhedrin meeting house, etc. As well, there were a lot of rooms and public hall-ways where the rabbis and lawyers discussed and debated matters of the Law (of Moses). This was more of an open area where any bold person could discuss a theological matter (by questionings) with the learned ones. [Akin to the place in Athens where Paul met with the philosophers on Mars Hill to discuss the news of the Resurrection.]
It was here in this atmosphere that the child Jesus mingled with the rabbis and "stumpted" them with His reasonings and insightful questionings. It was more of a public forum...which the Apostles also took advantage of when they preached about the Resurrection, or explained the supernatural healings which they did. Anyone was free to draw a crowd and orate!
Some commentators think that it was here that the events of the Day of Pentecost took place also. (See the last verses of the book of Luke: they were daily in the Temple praising God!) This location was feasible for the many international pilgrims to hear the glossolalia in progress, and see the erratic behavior of the disciples (drunkeness). (Acts 2)
Regardless, Jesus---or any one---would have been free to speak up in the grouping of the rabbis, lawyers, pharisees, saducees, or herodians, and enter into the discussions.

apparently there were more Synagogues than we have churches About 400 in Jerusalem alone.

@ Mike -  Now that you bring it up, it is well known that these small congregations vied for people on the Sabbath by having famous speakers come and speak  there! There was competition  amongst the rulers. Also note that not all the synagogues got along with each other. Some were ethnic congregations (see N.T. references), and some were divided on theological grounds. (See the history of Hillel and Shammai differences.) The violent reaction to some of Paul's preaching was not out of the common, according to the Jewish Encyclopaedia .
